# Moment.js returns Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The following code

```
const m = moment('08:45').format('HHmm')
```

returns

```
'Invalid date'
```

I have also tried `.format('HH:mm')`

Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Comment: Side note, why not just replace the colon in the input string with ""? Do you  really need `momentjs` for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead and pass in a format string as the second argument of the `moment()` function so that moment knows that you're passing in a time. So change your code to this:

```js
const m = moment('08:45', 'HH:mm').format('HHmm');
```

and you'll be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

The input string doesn't match any of the expected date formats, so you need to add a second argument to tell moment how to parse the input.

[String](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new Date(string) if a known format is not found.

[String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a
> moment.
>
> `moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");`

```js
const result = moment('08:45', 'HH:mm').format('HHmm');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```